# create new object in json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a json object like this

```
var data = postItem : [{
    id: 1,
content: 'Meeting with client 2pm'

},

{
id: 2,
content: 'Angularjs'
}]
```

and I want to add the 3rd object. I tried push but didn't work. even I assign it like       `$scope.postItem[5].content = $scope.newItem;` it won't work.

Do I need to create the empty object first?

Comment: That's not JSON. And `.push()` should work. Show what you tried.

Comment: $scope.postItem[5].content.push($scope.newItem);

Comment: Decode the JSON to an object first, modify the object then encode the JSON

Comment: @user3189052: Get rid of the `[5].content`. You call `.push()` against the Array, which is on the `postItem` property. `$scope.postItem.push($scope.newItem);` And FYI, the code in your question isn't valid syntax.

Comment: "Do I need to create the empty object first?" Yes, you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this in JavaScript

```
var users = {};
users.postItem = [
    { id: 1, content: 'Meeting with client 2pm' }
  , { id: 2, content: 'Angularjs' }
];
```

Output in JSON

```
JSON.stringify(users.postItem)
```

To add another object: (object count starts at zero - 0, if you know the index )

```
users.postItem[2] = { id: 3, content: 'Eat at joes' };
```

OR you can use the push method:

```
users.postItem.push({ id: 3, content: 'Eat at joes' });
```